# how can i embed python in c?

Tags: python, c

i wrote the C code as follow:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)

{

    PyObject *mod, *name, *func;
    Py_Initialize();
    mod = PyImport_ImportModule("perf_tester");
    if(!mod)
    {
        printf("cannot find perf_tester.py");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }
    name = PyObject_GetAttrString(mod, "CheckSharpness");
    if(!name)
    {
        printf("can not find CheckSharpness");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }
    func = PyObject_GetAttrString(name,"F");
    if(!func)
    {
        printf("can not find function");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

***except for func, i could find mod and name.***

and the partial of the perf_tester.py as follow:

```
def CheckSharpness(sample, edges, min_pass_mtf, min_pass_lowest_mtf,
           use_50p, mtf_sample_count, mtf_patch_width,
           mtf_crop_ratio=_MTF_DEFAULT_CROP_RATIO,
           n_thread=1):

  mtfs = [mtf_calculator.Compute(sample, line_start[t], line_end[t],
                                   mtf_patch_width, mtf_crop_ratio,
                                   use_50p)[0] for t in perm]

  F = open("data.txt","w")
  F.write(str(mtfs))
  F.close()
```

what could I do?

Comment: You should call `PyErr_PrintEx(0)` whenever a Python C API function fails. Also, don't tag C question as `c++`, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`F` is a local variable, it's not a member of `CheckSharpness`. It does not exist when `CheckSharpness` is not currently running, and each invocation of `CheckSharpness` has its own copy. There's no way to access this from outside.